# Which classes of matrices does P belong to

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question is :
*Which classes of matrices does $P$ belong to: orthogonal, invertible, Hermitian, unitary, factorizable into LU?*

$$P=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So P has rank=3 and all columns are linearly independent + length 1 + orthogonal. So P is definitely orthogonal. Is it invertible? Yes since R=M=N
Is it hermitian though? That's where the question comes in. P looks like a real matrix, can we classify it as hermitian in this case?

The thing is

*Can real matrices be hermitian, we all know that hermitian isn't the same thing with symmetric when the matrix is complex, but is it the same thing in real matrices since there is nothing to take conjugate of?*

Also, About "factorable into LU". What does it require to be factored into LU? Does it require 3 pivots? Nope, I've seen some examples with pivot

Thanks.

Comment: Yes.  Hermitian = symmetric when the matrix has real entries.  As for whether it admits an $LU$ decomp: the condition an invertible matrix has to satisfy is that each of its principal minors are nonzero.

Comment: what are principal minors? I can also LU decomp matrices that aren't invertible can't I?

Comment: The leading principal minors are the determinants of certain submatrices:  the $1\times 1$ submatrix containing only $a_{11}$, the $2\times 2$ submatrix containing the $a_{ij}$ for $i,j \in \{1,2\}$ entries, etc.  Yes there is also a condition for singular matrices, but since this one is invertible I gave you the relevant condition for this matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A matrix $A$ is hermitian if $a_{ij} = \overline{a_{ji}}$. Also, $a_{ji} \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow a_{ji} = \overline{a_{ji}}$. Thus, if $A \in \mathcal{M}_{mn}(\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C})$, then $A$ is hermitian if $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$, or in other words, if $A$ is symmetric.

A square matrix has a $LU$ decomposition if it has non-zero principal minors. In your case, one has

$$\begin{vmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{vmatrix} = 0,$$
hence $P$ can't be decomposed in a product $LU$. You need to perform some rows permutations (represented by a permutation matrix $P'$) before being able to decompose the matrix in the pattern $P = P'LU$. In your case, it's pretty obvious that

$$ P = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}}_{P'=P} \times \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}}_{L} \times \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}}_{U}.$$

However, this is only because $P$ was already a permutation matrix.

Comment: Okay I usee, so if something can't be LU decomposed PA could be. But since We always decompose with PA I got confused. Thanks, a lot of great help!